# Python will not execute the commands I type in

Tags: python

A basic math question in the python code I tried multiple variation from the original code in the class with no results. Such as `print('23+7')`. It won't do the calculation in any form it is written.

Comment: cause its a string, do `print(23+7)`

Comment: have a look at datatypes: `strings`, `integers`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(23+7)`, -> `''` or `""` define a string in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output to be in the form of a string, you can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) (python ≥3.6): `print(f'{23+7}')`